# Open a large mySQL DB and reduce it

Tags: mysql, joomla, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5

Exported a db from a Joomla website, it weighs about 1Giga,
Couldn't open it with MySQL workbench

This DB contains too much unnecessary spam users that fills this volume
I managed to open it with Visual studio eventually.
what is the right way to optimize and reduce the database size in VS
and would it work back when uploaded to server?.
Is there another way on Phpymyadmin?

[image]

Comment: ZIP the file and try to run it via phpMyAdmin.

Comment: use the normal client - mysql -uxxx -pxxx dbname < bigsql_file.sql

Comment: @mitkosoft I can run it on phpMyAdmin, how can I optimize it

Comment: Why does your database contain unnecessary tables and information?

Comment: @ceejayoz its simply filled with spam. and indexed by "smart search" module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting from a sql dump, your database, once loaded, is already optimized from a purely mechanical MySQL point of view. If VS or Workbench is having trouble opening this large db, try a more robust SQL client (e.g. HeidiSQL, SquirrelSQL, or plain old mysql command line). To get the spam users out of your db, therefore "reducing" it, you must identify them and delete them using Joomla administration actions or domain-specific sql queries.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I could not find the spam over the DB tables, in Joomla administration I found more than thousand posts in Russian as spam (under k2). therefore huge waste, it seems the SQL itself is optimized normally except that. just need to block future spam

Answer (score 1):

you can load it to your local machine and use [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/download.php) to connect your local mysql server

this is the command to load sql file

```
mysql -u [username] -p[password] [database] < [filename].sql
```

for example:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword123 wordpress < backup.sql
```

Comment: Thank you I managed to open the DB with HeidiSQL quite simply. Just need to delete the spam over there.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I found for the outrages DB size is "Smart search" module installed that Index the Joomla site, this module indexed a lot of spam as well.
once you disable this search and manage to delete all the spam posts out of Trashed K2 items, you get rid of all the spam, This spam can be deleted as well from the Mysql DB - > finder_terms Table. by selecting the spam posts ID or by their low Hits,

more about the issue I found here:
[http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=717711](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=717711.)